# What Symfony2 bundle is better for Neo4j integration?

Tags: symfony, neo4j, symfony-2.1

https://github.com/klaussilveira/neo4j-ogm-bundle

https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp

I am looking for more stable/ more active and wanted to see if you any one had experience with either one of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neo4jPHP is a simple REST client. You don't get any object mapping from it. If you don't like using ORMs and prefer to do your own querying/lookups, it is probably more your style.

Neo4j-OGM is a wrapper around Neo4jPHP that adds in ORM-type capabilities, annotations on your domain classes and a repository pattern. If you have ever used Doctrine or Propel, you will recognize the style and syntax.

My opinion: if you are used to using an ORM or ODM, go with Neo4j-OGM. If you like to do more tweaking and "bare-metal" optimizations, go with Neo4jPHP.